# How can self made ambient modules be created and imported in typescript?

Tags: typescript, webpack, ts-loader

I have an external javascript library that creates a global object in window.
To use this object in typescript code, I have created an ambient module file (d.ts) that is imported inside other typescript file.

The problem I am facing is that the compiler says that the module file is not a module

```
src/App.ts(6,22): error TS2306: File '/Users/user/ts-problems/src/abc.d.ts' is not a module.
```

I'm also using webpack with ts-loader but compiling it alone with (tsc) gives me the same result.

This is the abc.d.ts ambient module file

```
declare module "abc" {
    export interface Greeter {
        sayHello(): void;
    }
    export var abc: Greeter;
}
```

And this is the App.ts file:

```
import * as abc from "./abc";


class App {
    static sayGoodbye() {
        console.log("goodbye from App.ts");
    }
}

abc.abc.sayHello();
App.sayGoodbye();
```

The test project is available at https://github.com/daneilsan/ts-module-problem

Any help would be very appreciated because I don't know what else to do

Comment: just once doing `import './abc'` should be enough if the file is mapped correctly

Comment: @toskv it gives me the same result Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './abc' in '/Users/user/ts-problems/src'

Comment: Are you trying to import a package from npm called `abc`, or are you trying to import a local file that TypeScript doesn't know exists at `./abc`?

Comment: The abc.d.ts file is part of my project and is local. It is in the same folder as App.ts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The file `abc.d.ts` does not have any `export` or `imprort` statement at the top level, so it is not a module and can't be used with relative import. That is,

```
import ...some stuff... from "./abc";
```

fails.

However, there is no `files`, `include` or `exclude` present in your `tsconfig.json`, so by default, any file with `*.ts` or `*.d.ts` extension is included in the compilation.

That means `abc.d.ts` is included, so there is no need to `///reference` it, and all declarations within it are seen by the compiler, in particular this one:

```
declare module "abc" {
    ... stuff exported here
}
```

That means you can use this import

```
import * as abc from "abc";
```

to get stuff imported. It will be available as `abc.Greeter` and `abc.abc`.

This form

```
import {Greeter, abc} from "abc";
```

also works, making `Greeter` and `abc` available directly and not as properties of `abc` scope.

In short: to get things working, the module name in `import` statement must be spelled precisely in the same way as in the `declare module` statement (`"abc"`), and the file that contains `declare module` must be included in the compilation (it's already done by default with your `tscontig`).

Comment: You are right. The file abc.d.ts lacks "export". I have figured it out and changed the project also to use non-relative modules with BaseUrl tsconfig directive. You answer is very insightful. Thanks for it!